# Designing Real Time Web Application

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, real-time, xml-rpc

We have a real time application where AppServer( written in c/c++) used to broadcast network event details
(typically few hundred to around thousand rows with around 40-50 columns per second) to Client GUI app written in gtk
 over network using XML/RPC, as well as writing to DB(running on same machine or LAN). 95% communication is from server to client. 
It was working fine with no issues.

We have to port the application to web. In initial attempt we kept C/C++ app server  as it is. Now we are sending the data to java web 
application server through xml/rpc. Java server keeps a circular queue (initially kept small size of 2000) and pushes data
 to client through websockets. At client we are using angular ui-grid to display the data.

Currently the problem is browser can not handle this amount of data at this frequency and 
after some time (few hours) become unresponsive. This is a network monitoring app supposed to be run 24/7 and though we have very few 
users, we don't have much control over their machine's configuration (mostly low/medium end). Server (tomacat 8) was running on 2*6 core, 16 GB RAM.

Can you give suggestions for improving browser performance? We are even ready to implement new solution from scratch. 
But I think browser performance will be always the bottlneck.

Comment: So are you constantly pushing data (rows) for the browser to display? In that case, the DOM keeps growing, so at some point, it will be so huge that the browser won't be able to cope, and that's normal. There's no point displaying all 200 million lines in one page. Just display the relevant info at one given time.

Comment: what size you recommend for this "active window"?

Comment: we tried to keep this size to as low as 500 to 1000 rows. But the server generates data at high rate, even this rate is hampering browser. The system( or browser) must handle at least few hundred rows every second.

Answer (score 0):

if the pushed data is persisted somewhere else, you should implement a worker to clean the browser data periodically.

For an example say you have been pushing 1000 records per minute, and the browser crashes around one hour period, you could implement a worker where every half an hour, it cleans the browser DOM in order to keep the memory footprint at its lowest.

To access previous data, you should have an API implemented where a user could fetch data for a given time/data period.

it's hard to identify what is causing the crashes, but IMO it should be a heavy DOM which the browser is unable to handle after a certain time. It's better if you could provide an details report of the browser when it crashed.

Comment: by worker, do you mean web worker? In that case it doesn't have access to DOM

Comment: Nope not exactly a webworker, but a worker which is continuously monitoring your DOM for excessive usage.

Comment: I am deleting rows at regular intervals from JSON array which is assigned as data array to UI Grid so that totals rows always remain at fixed number(300 or 500). Is it enough or do I need to clean DOM explicitly?